# Weird scrolling lines in video while using Akaso EK7000 in low light

Tags: action-cam

I got the Akaso EK7000 action cam in the mail today. The camera works almost perfectly other than one issue I noticed. The issue I noticed is a scrolling line that appears in the video at 4k 25fps. I then took about the same clip in the same conditions at 1080p 60fps and I didn't notice the issue. Here are the clips I took.

4k 25fps:

[Video on Vimeo (password: video)](http://vimeo.com/252274311)

1080p 60fps:

[Video in Vimeo (password: video)](https://vimeo.com/252274385)

Also, the lines on the walls in both clip aren't caused by the camera, they are just shadows from a railing behind me.

I've heard about something called rolling shutter, could this be caused by that at all?

Answer (score 3):

that's the frame rate and electricity frequency

Ill bet if you filmed at 1080 25fps you would get the same result. Im going to assume you are based in the US which uses the standard 30fps which is why your 1080 footage does not show it as 60fps is a multiple of 30fps but 25fps is not which is why you are getting the banding.

Hope that helps

FYI there is nothing you can do in camera unless the 4k offers a 30fps (or multiple of) to avoid the banding when filming with standard household lighting

Comment: Well that could still be the same issue. I’ve had it before while filming LED lights that I had to drop to 40fps to remove the flicker. It’s all going to be down to the frequency of the electric in the end. There are quite a few YouTube and blog posts explaining this with examples etc

Answer (score 0):

you probably have already figured it out, but for new guys googling this:

I got the [Apexcam 4K 20MP WIFI Action Camera](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07HP18CWC/)

All I had to do is change the 'Frequency' settings from 50hz to 60hz. That solved most of the problems, only the 1080p 60fps mode still has those lines, don't know what to do about that. All other modes work fine. If your camera has a frequency setting, might work for you, if it doesn't, you might have to limit shooting outside with constant lighting (not artificial sources like streetlamps).